# LSTM for image sequences- AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'float'

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

Further to my previous post,
[LSTM-CNN to classify sequences of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195464/lstm-cnn-to-classify-sequences-of-images),
I got further and I am now  running the below code:

```
 loop += 1
        if loop % 50 == 0:
            # calculate Accuracy
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through the test dataset
    
            for j in range(iter):
                sequences = x_test[bs:bs + batch_size, :]
                labels_t = y_test[bs:bs + batch_size]
                test_images = dataset.load_images(sequences)
                bs += batch_size
                test_images = (torch.from_numpy(test_images)).view(-1, 4, 784)
                print('test_image_shape {} - iter: {}'.format(test_images.shape, j))
                labels_t = torch.from_numpy(labels_t)
                labels_t  = torch.argmax(labels_t, dim=1)
                test_outputs = model(test_images).float() 
                pred_y = torch.max(test_outputs, 1)[1].data.numpy().squeeze()
               
                total += labels_t.size(0)
                correct += (pred_y == labels_t).float()
                accuracy = 100 * (correct / total)
           
                print('Iteration:{}. Loss:{}. Accuracy{}:'.format(loop, loss.item(), accuracy))
```

However it is giving me the following error:

> correct += (pred_y == labels_t).float()
> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'float'

correct is always resulting in 0 and so is accuracy.

I am suspecting that it has to do with a certain package or requirement, because I searched and it seems that it should work. Any idea what could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

That's because pred_y is that numpy.ndarray and labels_t is torch.tensor.
If you compare two variables as torch.tensor, you can get float value
but the variables' type is not equal.
so python said tow variables are not the same type(so return False)

you use below code for convert torch.tensor to numpy.ndarray

```
pred_y = torch.max(test_outputs, 1)[1].data.numpy().squeeze()
```

I think you can implement like this.

```
pred_y = torch.max(test_outputs, 1)[1].squeeze()
```

Please try this one!

Comment: Thank you , I did and was able to pass that line but in the end it gave the following error : <correct += (pred_y == labels_t).float()
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 0>. Plus the print statement at the end is giving the following result :<Iteration:50. Loss:1.935647964477539. Accuracy tensor([20.6271, 21.7822, 18.8119]):> accuracy is returned as a tensor.

Comment: first, you can calculate the number of correct like (pred_y == label_t).sum().item().
Second, the shape of pred_y and label_t must be the same.